# How can I colour-fill a plotted shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, pgfmath

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\tikzset{variable/.default=}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10} 

\colorlet{ColorPink}{brown!25}
\colorlet{colourGreen}{green!15}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{every node}=[->,line width = 0.05mm]

\begin{scope}[shift={(0.0,5.1,0)}]
\draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] ({270+16*sin(\t)}: 
{5.1*pow(sin(\t/2),10)});
\draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] ({298+12*sin(\t)}: 
{5.8*pow(sin(\t/2),4)});

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produced the following figure.

[image: Capture1]

However, I desire to have the shapes in the figure filled with any specified colour as shown in the following figure.

[image]

I am not sure how to do this. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as simple as adding `fill=<color>` to the respective path.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\colorlet{ColorPink}{brown!25}
\colorlet{colourGreen}{green!15}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[shift={(0.0,5.1,0)}]
  \draw[fill=ColorPink] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] ({270+16*sin(\t)}: 
   {5.1*pow(sin(\t/2),10)});
  \draw[fill=colourGreen] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] ({298+12*sin(\t)}: 
   {5.8*pow(sin(\t/2),4)});
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I removed all the libraries that were not used here, and `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: Excellent! I tried severally to use the fillbetween command but didn't get the required result. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is function of `scope`?

Comment: @Zarko I think you know the answer. The assumption is that the OP will add stuff outside of the `scope`. This seems to be part of a 3d-like diagram.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, goof point. You are excellent in assumption :-).  I only saw that it has no role in this particular case :-(, so I asked.